# Reshaping tensor in custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm getting None type when reshaping the tensor. This happens when compiling the model with loss function and the optimizer (before starting the training). What do I do?

Error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, -1). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Custom loss function:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

        y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (K.get_variable_shape(y_pred)[0], -1))
        y_true = K.reshape(y_true, (K.get_variable_shape(y_true)[0], -1))
        y_pred = K.std(y_pred, axis=0)
        y_true = K.std(y_true, axis=0)
        loss = (1/2) * (y_pred - y_true) ** 2
        loss = K.mean(loss)

        return loss
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your `y_true` or `y_pred` tensors shape is not defined properly. `None` means here that the tensors shape is not strictly set, but it can vary based on the previous operations what we can't see. Or you just initialized your tensor like this.

How to fix it:

- First you should investigate how the `y_true` or `y_pred` gets its shape and avoid getting a None shape, so the tensors will have a deterministic number of rows and cols

Example:

Your loss function works for proper inputs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K


def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (K.get_variable_shape(y_pred)[0], -1))
    y_true = K.reshape(y_true, (K.get_variable_shape(y_true)[0], -1))
    y_pred = K.std(y_pred, axis=0)
    y_true = K.std(y_true, axis=0)
    loss = (1 / 2) * (y_pred - y_true) ** 2

    return loss


a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2., 3.]])
b = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])
loss = custom_loss(a, b)
loss = tf.Print(loss, [loss], "loss")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    _ = sess.run([loss])
```

But when using a placeholder where I have not defined the shape, will throw the same exception

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32))
```

Comment: Please then accept it as a solution, to help other find the right solution quickly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

        y_pred = K.reshape(y_pred, (K.shape(y_pred)[0], -1))
        y_true = K.reshape(y_true, (K.shape(y_true)[0], -1))
        y_pred = K.std(y_pred, axis=0)
        y_true = K.std(y_true, axis=0)
        loss = (1/2) * (y_pred - y_true) ** 2
        loss = K.mean(loss)

        return loss
```

The problem was with finding the first dimension of the y_true and y_predict. During compilation, it will not get a true shape and hence it returns a None value. So, instead of getting the integer value of the shape, I get the tf.Tensor shape. I changed  K.get_variable_shape(y_true) to just K.shape(y_true) and it solves.